# Полила — какое ударение в слове?

Tags: орфоэпия

Какое ударение в слове "полила"?

Comment: если палИла - получается, что сожгла, съЕла. А если пэлилА - то отдалА(воду).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим орфоэпический словарь: полилА.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]